# How do I access stored properties from another UIViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How can I add append addedItem in SecondViewController to items array in FirstViewController programmatically?

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

     var items: [String] = []
}
```

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

     let textField: UITextField = UITextField()
     let saveButton: UIButton = UIButton()

     @objc func saveButtonTapped() {
          let addedItem = textField.text
     }
}
```

Comment: You can use a delegation pattern or a shared model object

Comment: https://www.advancedswift.com/how-to-create-a-custom-delegate-in-swift/#:~:text=In%20Swift%2C%20a%20delegate%20is,UIApplicaitonDelegate%20in%20an%20iOS%20app.